# Regex to extract string between two strings separated by newline

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like below:

```
Movies(s):   
DIE ANOTHER DAY  
TOMORROW NEVER DIES  
WORLD IS NOT ENOUGH  
Running Date(s):
```

I want to extract the movie names as separate matches not as a whole like below:

```
Match 1: DIE ANOTHER DAY  
Match 2: TOMORROW NEVER DIES  
Match 3: WORLD IS NOT ENOUGH
```

I tried to use lookahead and lookbehind but couldn't succeed in getting three matches.

Comment: You need to specify a language.

Comment: Java. I added the tag as java also

Comment: split to an array on a newline and ignore the first and last elements?

Comment: Sounds like http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Comment: @AlexK. yes that's possible. but i need to use only regex. no other way

Comment: @LiquidPie - *why* can you use nothing other than regular expressions ? Is this homework ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew here only regex is used to extract data and then java just utilizes the data. Since, java part is not handled by myself

Comment: What separates the movie titles? In other words, how do I know that one move is "DIE ANOTHER DAY" followed by "TOMORROW NEVER DIES" rather than one movie called "DIE ANOTHER DAY TOMORROW NEVER DIES"?

Comment: @DJClayworth Movie names are separated by [CR][LF]

Comment: @anubhava yes, it always has. Also, this is just an excerpt from a long string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using following regex:

```
(?s)(?<=Movie\(s\)\:\s{0,3}\r{0,1}\n.{0,100})([A-Z \.]+)(?=.{0,100}Running\Date\(s\)\:)
```

Comment: When you test this make sure you try the movies "12 MONKEYS" and "STAR TREK: INTO DARKNESS"

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner:

```
String[] movies = str.replaceAll(".*Movies\\(s\\):\\s*|Running Date\\(s\\):.*", "").split("[\n\r]+");
```

This code first strips off the front/back, leaving just the movie names, then splits on (platform independent) newline chars.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the discard technique through a regex like this:

```
.*:|^(.+)$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/wS3jF5/2)**

The idea behind the discard technique is to use a chain of pattern that you want to get rid off. So, you can have something like this:

```
discard patt1 | discard patt2 | discard pattN | (capture this)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Applying this technique to your string, you can modify above regex to something like this:

```
Movies\(s\):|Running Date\(s\):|(.+)
discard--^   discard--^  capture--^
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/wS3jF5/3)**

You can see easily with this diagram:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [11-26] `DIE ANOTHER DAY`
MATCH 2
1.  [27-46] `TOMORROW NEVER DIES`
MATCH 3
1.  [47-66] `WORLD IS NOT ENOUGH`
```

You can use this Java code:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(".*:|^(.+)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
// or this line:
//     Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("Movies\\(s\\):|Running Date\\(s\\):|(.+)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher("YOUR STRING HERE");
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(regexMatcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "Movies(s):\r\n" +
        "DIE ANOTHER DAY\r\n" +
        "TOMORROW NEVER DIES\r\n" +
        "WORLD IS NOT ENOUGH\r\n" +
        "Running Date(s):";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(([A-Z ]+)[\r\n]{1,2})");

Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);

int index = 0;
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(++index + "," + m.group(2));
}
```

And the output will be(tested):

```
1,DIE ANOTHER DAY
2,TOMORROW NEVER DIES
3,WORLD IS NOT ENOUGH
```